# OneSignal Xamarin.Forms HandleNotificationOpened redirect to notification specific page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, onesignal

in my Xamarin.Forms project I use OneSignal for notifications. In iOS *Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new NotificationPage());* worked but in Android this not work. I tried to use messaging center to communicate with PCL project. It worked when app is background but not working when app is closed. How can I redirect notification specific page when notification received in Android? Thanks

Note : Code edited and issue solved, I used shared preferences to control if app launched from notification or not. Then I Load xamarin.Forms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note : Code edited and issue solved, I used shared preferences to control if app launched from notification or not. Then I Load xamarin.Forms application**

```
public class MainActivity : 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{



 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        InitializeUI();

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
        tV = new TextView(this);
        resources = this.Resources;


        OneSignal.Current.StartInit("***APP ID***")
           .InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
           .HandleNotificationReceived(HandleNotificationReceived)
            .HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened)
             .EndInit();


        ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        var LaunchFromNotification = prefs.GetString("is_notification_received", "false");
        if (LaunchFromNotification == "true")
        {
            LoadApplication(new App(true));

        }
        else
        {
            LoadApplication(new App(false));

        }

        OneSignal.Current.IdsAvailable(IdsAvailable); //Lets you retrieve the OneSignal player id and push token.
    }

}
        private static void HandleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
    {
        ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Android.App.Application.Context);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
        editor.PutString("is_notification_received", "true");
        editor.Apply();

    }
protected override void OnResume()
       {
            base.OnResume();
            ISharedPreferences prefs = 
     PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
        editor.Remove("is_notification_received");
        editor.PutString("is_notification_received", "false");
        editor.Apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method before LoadApplication() method is called.

```
if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);                        
                    Log.Debug(TAG, "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
                }
            }
        }

 LoadApplication(new App());
```

You have to set intent.putExtra() method in OnMessageReceivedMethod().

```
intent.PutExtra("Key", "value");
```

Then you can use redirection in App.xaml.cs file based on this key value. Because in android when notification is open while app is reinitialized.

I think you don't need to put below condition.

```
 if (extrasList[0] == "true")
    {
        LoadApplication(new App(true));

    }
    else
    {
        LoadApplication(new App(false));

    }
```

First Store your value global level so you can use it in App.cs file. Just use below code to handle page navigation in App() class like.

```
 if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                {
                    if (YourKey == "true")
                    {
                       //handle that page navigation
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //Default Page of App
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect when App Initialized. Right?

Comment: Yes I am passing as an argument to constructor of App()

Comment: So When App is closed and you are opening app from notification then Intent Value is not setting. Right?

Comment: Can you share your MainActivity Code Please?

Comment: By using shared preferences in Android, I stored a value when notification received and then I check that value while loading app. That worked for me

Comment: @OguzhanOrhan Okay. Great.